# How to make a div hidden by default made by a content_tag_for

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have made a div through content_tag_for and I wish to make it hidden by default. How do I do that? I am using jquery as well.

Answer (score 5):

Attach a class:

```
content_tag_for(:div, @person, :class => "hidden") { # blah blah }
```

And define it as hidden in the stylesheet:

```
div.hidden { display: none }
```

Note: you can also use `div_for`, which saves some code. See the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: +1 -- I prefer this method (although the other answer works) because there is no initial flash of content before the document is ready and .hide() is fired.

Answer (score 2):

Wont this work since you mention you are using JQuery?

In HEAD of Page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#your-div-id').hide();
});
</script>
```

Or in BODY of Page AFTER the div you are creating, just:

```
<script>
  $('#your-div-id').hide();
</script>
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?
Thanks.